# Alternative to Map.set(key, list) always points to the same list

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures

The following code is supposed to build a map that contains (id, domainList), as the current JS version doesn't allow `Map.set()` (it doesn't even recognize `Map()`).

When using `testMap[key] = domainList`, it always points to the same `domainList` rather than other lists like `Map.set()` does. It always points to a single `domainList`.

What would be the cause of this?

```
testMap = {};

for (var key in idSet) {

    iterator = data.iterator();

    var domainList = [];

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        var tuple = iterator.next();

        var domain = tuple["Domain"];
        var current_Id = tuple["Id"];

        if (current_Id == key) {
            domainList.push(domain);
        }
    }

    testMap[key] = domainList;
    domainList.lengh() = 0;
```

Comment: Can you provide `idSet` and `data` ?

Comment: I solve this problem by declaring several domainList[], and using testMap[key] = domainList[i] with index by counting.